# C++: why can protected constructor be called directly when a class object is defined?

Tags: c++, oop

I read an article online, the source codes are:

```
      class ASingleton
    {
    public:
        static ASingleton* getInstance()
        {
            return &m_data;
        }
        void do_something()
        {
            cout<<"ASingleton do_something!"<<endl;
        }
    protected:
        static ASingleton m_data; //static data member 在类中声明，在类外定义
        ASingleton();
        ~ASingleton() {}
    };

    class BSingleton
    {
    public:
        static BSingleton* getInstance()
        {
            return &m_data;
        }
        void do_something()
        {
            cout<<"BSingleton do_something!"<<endl;
        }
    protected:
        static BSingleton m_data; //static data member 在类中声明，在类外定义
        BSingleton();
        ~BSingleton() {}
    };

    ASingleton ASingleton::m_data;
    BSingleton BSingleton::m_data;

    ASingleton::ASingleton()
    {
        cout<<"ASingleton constructor!"<<endl;
        BSingleton::getInstance()->do_something();
    }

    BSingleton::BSingleton()
    {
        cout<<"BSingleton constructor!"<<endl;
    }

    int main()
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

after running it, the results are:

```
    ASingleton constructor!
    BSingleton do_something!
    BSingleton constructor!
```

my question is: the constructors for both classes are protected, why can't they be called by definitions (ASingleton ASingleton::m_data; BSingleton BSingleton::m_data;)? I think protected functions can only be called in subclasses, aren't they?

Comment: `m_data` is within the scope of `ASingleton` so it can use private and protected members. You could not write `ASingleton foo;` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no violation here. `ASingleton` has the `public static` method `getInstance()` which returns the instance.

Since `getInstance()` is a member of `ASingleton` it has full access to all the methods implemented in its class. It doesn't become external to the class just because it's `static`.

Additionally, `m_data` is just an in-class instance of these singletons. They are statically initialized at runtime within the scope of their own class declaration.

Comment: but the getInstance() is not called in the main() or in the object definition

Comment: Right, it doesn't need to be because each class also contains `static` instances of itself

Comment: you mean it is the declaration (inside the class) but not the definition(outside the class) that implicitly calls the constructor ? isn't the definition that implicitly calls the constructor?

Comment: a static field inside a class is simply the declaration - it doesn't come into "existence" until it's definition. Nonetheless, the definition is considered to be within the scope of the class itself just as function definitions are.